# OrientDB embeddedmap query

Tags: sql, orientdb

Let's say I have a Vertex class Data in OrientDB. Data has a property data which is of the type EMBEDDEDMAP.

I can create a new Vertex of this type and assign an object to the property data with the following command:

```
CREATE VERTEX Data SET data = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
```

Let's say now that I want to query the database and get records that holds exactly this structure in the data property.

Ie, something in the lines of:

```
SELECT FROM Data WHERE data = {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
```

This doesn't work however (Note also that the structure in data is arbitrary and can have nested structures: {"key2":{"key2":"val2"}} etc.)

I know that this query is possible for an embeddedmap type:

```
SELECT FROM Data WHERE "val1" IN data.key1 AND "val2" IN data.key2
```

But for arbitrary data structures it would be bothersome to parse such a query, this also made me find out another thing:

Let's say I create two vertices:

```
CREATE VERTEX Data SET data = {"key1":["one", "two"]} 
CREATE VERTEX Data SET data = {"key1":["one"]}
```

I now want to select only the first of them, for instance with:

```
SELECT FROM Data WHERE ["one", "two"] IN data.key1
```

This query however returns both records:

```
@rid    @version    @class  data
#13:7   1           Data    {"key1":["one","two"]}
#13:8   1           Data    {"key1":["one"]}
```

I'm guessing I have to do:

```
SELECT FROM Data WHERE "one" IN data.key1 AND "two" IN data.key1
```

However, this also seems quite cumbersome for nested lists.

**Question: How could I query on a known, arbitrary data structure (embeddedmap)**

NOTE: I'm not asking about specific values in the structure, but the whole structure.